# EFCore Bulk Insert & SQLite In Memory: no such table: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS"

Tags: c#, sqlite, entity-framework-core, sqlbulkcopy, in-memory-database

I'm using [EFCore BulkExtensions](https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions) 2.5.0 with Entity Framework Core 2.2.3 and EFCore.SQLite 2.2.6.

I have code like this:

```cs
// Repo that throws exception on BulkInsert
public class UserRepository
{
   private readonly IDbContextProvider<ReportContext> _dbContextProvider;
  
   public async Sync(IList<User> users)
   { 
        await _dbContextProvider.Context.BulkInserOrUpdateAsync(users);
   }
}

// Poco Model
public class User
{
   public string Id {get;set;}
   public string Name {get; set;}
}

// Simple DbContext
public class ReportsContext : DbContext
{
   public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

My application code (which uses `EFCore.Sql`) runs this just fine. But when my test code runs using SQLite in-memory, I get an exception:

> No such table: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
>
> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException : SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS'.
>
> at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
> at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.PrepareAndEnumerateStatements(Stopwatch timer)+MoveNext()
> at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
> at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteCommand.ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync(CommandBehavior behavior, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at EFCore.BulkExtensions.TableInfo.CheckHasIdentityAsync(DbContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at EFCore.BulkExtensions.SqlBulkOperation.MergeAsync[T](DbContext context, IList`1 entities, TableInfo tableInfo, OperationType operationType, Action`1 progress, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> at MyCode.Repositories.UserRepository.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<b__0>d.MoveNext() in C:\projects\MyCode\Repositories\UserRepository.cs:line 48

`INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` isn't part of my data model and isn't something I'm trying to create or work with. Do I need to configure or tweak EF Core or SQLite to get it to support bulk operations when operation in-memory mode?

I've tried [turning on EF Core logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging?tabs=v3) and can see my Db Model being processed and tables being created, but no output on the bulk operations, so I'm unsure what generated SQL statements are looking for this `Information_Schema.Columns` table.

Comment: You have a base class DbRead with two inherited classed Core and SQLite.  So you cannot cast one inherited class Core to SQLite which is basically what is causing the error.  To change databases you have to update the mapping between the database and the c# classes when you change databases.

Comment: @jdweng - I'm not sure I follow.   I'm using EF Core, I don't think there is a `DbRead` class.  I'm using Model Snapshots - are you thinking there's an issue there where there's an incompatibility between the model builder for sql vs sqlite?

Comment: Yes.  You probably need to refresh the mapping file between the database and the c# classes. The DbRead is the base class that is used in database classes that are generated by Entity.

Comment: Can you tell me how to refresh my database classes?  I did a search through my solution and didn't find the term `DbRead` anywhere.  And I thought part of EF's magic is it wasn't specific to any one Db, it should be ok to have my test code use sql lite and my prod code use Sql.  There will be a few provider specific caveats, but for the basic stuff I'm trying to do, it should largely be ok?

Comment: See : https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/create-and-update-an-edmx-file-using-entity-framework-data-model-in-visual-stud/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is a bug in EFCore.BulkExtensions for `2.5.0` where it didn't have full SQLite support.  It works with version `2.6.4`:  https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions/issues/308